# NetBeans 12.3 user input on console not working

Tags: java, netbeans, console, user-input

I've run into something curious with NetBeans 12.3.  I have some simple code like this:

```
System.out.printf("Welcome!%n%n");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.printf("Enter your name: ");
String name = input.nextLine();
```

When I run this all I get is the output "Welcome!". I do not see "Enter your name: ". But if do type something into the console - like abcd - and click enter, then the output will be "Enter your name: abcd"

I haven't experienced this with previous versions.

Thoughts?

Comment: You didn't state your Java version or your project type or your O/S, but I just ran a trivial Ant application on NetBeans 12.3 using JDK-15 on Windows with your exact code in `main()`, and it worked fine. That is, I saw _"Enter your name: "_ just by running the application, without needing to input any data first. FYI, it also ran fine when using 12.4 and JDK 16. So your issue is probably related to the JDK you are using, or the way you created the project in NetBeans. Update your question with sufficient detail so that others can attempt to exactly replicate what you are doing.

Comment: Maven project with Maven 3.6.3 and Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your problem using your environment (NB 12.3/JDK 15/Maven 3.6.3), and also with NB 12.4/JDK 16/Maven 3.6.3 and NB 8.2/JDK 8/Maven 3.6.1. The issue always occurs with Maven projects, but never occurs with Ant projects.

A similar problem has been bug reported to NetBeans. See [NETBEANS-4812:](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4812)

> System.out.print() statements placed before Scanner calls, such as
> scanner::next(), do not output until after input is entered only in
> Netbeans console.

NetBeans closed the bug report as "*invalid*", with the following comments:

> This is not a Netbeans issue. This is a Maven issue.  When you run in
> Netbeans, it delegates the work to Maven on command line. In the
> output window copy the first line into a terminal and run. You will
> face the same issue... Closing this issue
>
> Not a Netbeans issue. Can reproduce on Terminal in Maven exec

You have a couple of possible solutions. One is to create your project using Ant instead of Maven, although that is only a workaround. A better approach is to amend the default settings of your Maven project in a couple of places:

- First, select your Maven project, right click and select **Properties** from the displayed menu.
- In the **Project Properties** window select the **Actions** entry from the **Categories** list, and then select **Run project** from the **Actions** list.
- The **Execute Goals** field will have the value `process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec`. Replace the final four characters, "`exec`", with "`java`".
- In the **Set Properties** field append this line `exec.mainClass=${packageClassName}`.

After doing that the two modified fields should look similar to this:

[image: MavenSettings]

If you then rebuild and run your Maven project it will work as expected.

Notes:

- See [Exec Maven Plugin – Running Java Programs from Maven Build](https://www.journaldev.com/33793/exec-maven-plugin-run-java-programs-maven-build) for more information on changing the execute goal from **exec** to **java**.
- As noted in the bug report, calling `System.out.flush()` to force the writing of buffered content did not help. (I verified that, but do not understand why it doesn't fix your problem.)

Answer (score 0):

I reverted to Maven 3.3.9 and that fixed the problem with Maven 3.6.3